Can't seem to Connect to PowerBI API (Streaming Dataset) via powershell
I can not seem to connect to my PowerBI Streaming DataSet via powershell. The functionality i want to achieve is the following: I have a Streraming Dateset and a Dashboard of that Dataset. The dashboard shows new Tickets that users have created. Those are being sent via HTTP Posts to my streaming dataset. This Dashboard is being shown in our IT-Office on a TV Screen. Since it isn't very noticeable when the dahsboard updates, i want to include a sound that plays when the dashboard updates. Here is the Powershell Script i have come up with:
I have "blurred out" all the details like $datasetID and so on. However, to my knowledge they are all correct.
# Define the necessary variables
$datasetId = "X"
$groupId = "X"
$soundFilePath = "C:\Temp\Wasted.mp3"  # Single backslashes for file path
$previousRowCountFile = "C:\Temp\previousRowCount.txt"  # Single backslashes for file path

# Service principal details
$clientId = "X"
$clientSecret = "X"
$tenantId = "X"

# Function to connect to Power BI using service principal
function Connect-PowerBI {
    $tokenBody = @{
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
        client_id     = $clientId
        client_secret = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new('',$clientSecret).Password
        scope         = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"
    }

    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body $tokenBody
    $token = $tokenResponse.access_token

    # Return the access token
    return $token
}

# Function to get the current row count of the dataset
function Get-RowCount {
    $accessToken = Connect-PowerBI
    $header = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"
        'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    }
    
    try {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/datasets/$datasetId/tables" -Headers $header -ErrorAction Stop
        $rowCount = $response.Count  # Assuming 'Count' property exists in the response
        return $rowCount
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to retrieve dataset."
        return 0
    }
}

# Function to play sound
function Play-Sound {
    param (
        [string]$soundFile
    )
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Media;
public class SoundPlayer {
    public static void PlaySound(string path) {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(path);
        player.PlaySync();
    }
}
"@
    [SoundPlayer]::PlaySound($soundFile)
}

# Read the previous row count from the file, if it exists
if (Test-Path $previousRowCountFile) {
    $previousRowCount = [int](Get-Content $previousRowCountFile)
} else {
    $previousRowCount = 0
}

# Get the current row count
$currentRowCount = Get-RowCount

# Compare the current row count with the previous row count
if ($currentRowCount -gt $previousRowCount) {
    # Play the notification sound
    Play-Sound -soundFile $soundFilePath
}

# Save the current row count to the file
Set-Content -Path $previousRowCountFile -Value $currentRowCount

The following Error Message is being returned:
*Get-RowCount : Failed to retrieve dataset.
In C:\Temp\CheckDatasetUpdates.ps1:71 Zeichen:20
+ $currentRowCount = Get-RowCount
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-RowCount*

I have probably wasted half a day on this script which is quite embarrasing. I'm honestly out of ideas, since i usually don't work with scripts.
These are the instructions i followed to setup the "backend" if you wanna call it that:

Register an Application in Azure AD


Go to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com).
Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "App registrations".
Click on "New registration".
Provide a name for the application, e.g., "PowerBIScriptApp".
Select the appropriate supported account types (Single tenant is usually sufficient).
Click "Register".


Configure API Permissions



After registering, navigate to "API permissions".
Click "Add a permission".
Select "Power BI Service".
Choose "Application permissions".
Add the required permissions, such as "Dataset.ReadWrite.All".
Click "Add permissions".
Grant admin consent for the permissions by clicking "Grant admin consent for [Your Organization]".


Create a Client Secret

Navigate to "Certificates & secrets".

Click "New client secret".
Provide a description and expiration period.
Click "Add".
Copy the secret value and store it securely. You will need it later.


Assign Power BI Service Principal Permissions


Go to the Power BI Admin Portal (https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal).
Navigate to "Tenant settings".
Ensure that "Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs" is enabled.
Optionally, restrict this to specific security groups.


Answer:
Your can not use "My Workplace". You need to store your dataset, report and so on in a new Workplace. You also need to add your Service Principle and Security Group to that Workplace as members as shown in
Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret
To be clear, i can still not pull data from my streaming dataset. When i do, the Data Array is empty. So far i have not been able to solve this issue but atleast i no longer get the error message from above.
